# Is a linear functional which is positive on linearly generating set of projections positive?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital C$^*$ algebra, and suppose there is a set of projections $P \subset \mathcal{P}(A)$ whose linear span is dense in $A$. If $\varphi \in A^*$ has $\varphi(p) \ge 0$ for all $p \in P$, does it follow that $\varphi \ge 0$?

Note that this does hold if every element of $A$ can be approximated in norm by a linear combination of *mutually orthogonal* projections in $P$ (given any $x^*x \in A_+$, such an approximation for $x$ will lead to an approximation of $x^*x$ by a linear combination with positive coefficients), but is there any reason to believe it in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Take $A=\mathbb C^2$, $\varphi(a,b)=2a-b$, and 
$$
\mathcal P=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}. 
$$
Then $\operatorname{span}\mathcal P=A$, and $\varphi(1,0)=2$, $\varphi(1,1)=1$. But $\varphi$ is not positive, since $\varphi(0,1)=-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You are absolutely right. As you may have guessed, this isn't quite the question I intended to ask (I am interested in the case where $A$ is concretely represented and $P$ is a complemented lattice). But I am new to stack exchange, so I'm not sure how to proceed. Is the appropriate procedure to accept this answer and ask a new question, or should I edit this one? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: The etiquette here is to ask a new question. Users look down on edits to questions that invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Ok thanks, that was my intuition. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem :) $ $

Comment: What if $A$ is simple ?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3112219/22857).